# Open Dialogbox with Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, dialog

I am trying to open up a website(Google DialogFlow Chat BOT) in my website using JQuery load function.

My Code is as shown below.

```
<a href="#" id="configs">ChatBOT</a>
<div id="configs-dialog"  title="ChatBOT">
        </div>

    
    $("#configs").ready( function() {
                    $( "div#configs-dialog" ).dialog({
                        autoOpen: false,
                        height: 400,
                        width: 600,
                        modal: true,
                        buttons: {
                            Close: function() {
                                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    <!-- On Click function for terms dialog -->
                    $('#configs').click(function(){ $('div#configs-dialog').dialog('open'); });
                        
                } );
                <!-- load configs html -->
                $(function(){
                    $("#configs-dialog").load("https://console.dialogflow.com/api-client/demo/embedded/bbdd7d51-741c-4308-82c0-fc70073b057e"); 
                });
```

I am not able to load the website into the dialog window.
It opens up a blank dialog box when I click on the link.
Can any one please help me with this?

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example I do not see where `#configs-dialog` is defined in your HTML.

Comment: @Twisty I added the Html code for the configs-dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this sort of element, you cannot use `.load()` as it will only load the elements and not the JavaScript that is needed.

> When calling `.load()` using a URL without a suffixed selector expression, the content is passed to `.html()` prior to scripts being removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. If `.load()` is called with a selector expression appended to the URL, however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated, and thus are not executed.

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, port, or protocol.

Consider using an iFrame instead.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#configs-dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 400,
    width: 600,
    modal: true,
    buttons: [{
      text: "Close",
      class: "ui-state-primary",
      click: function(e) {
        var results = confirm("Are you sure you want to close the ChatBOT?");
        if (results) {
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
        return false;
      }
    }]
  });

  $('#configs').click(function() {
    $('#configs-dialog').dialog('open');
    $("#configs-dialog")
      .html("")
      .append($("<iframe>", {
          class: "configs-dialog-frame",
          src: "https://console.dialogflow.com/api-client/demo/embedded/bbdd7d51-741c-4308-82c0-fc70073b057e"
        })
        .css("height", $("#configs-dialog").height() - 5));
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar {
  display: none;
}

.ui-dialog #configs-dialog.ui-dialog-content {
  padding: 0;
}

.configs-dialog-frame {
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="configs">ChatBOT</a>
<div id="configs-dialog" title="ChatBOT"></div>
```